# passing url parameter to $match query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I take ObjectId from Url parameter to obtain a data in Aggregate $match?
For example, I have userID and I want to match teacher fields with userID which I pass to the URL parameter?
it is like this

```
{ 
   $match : 
   { 
   "teacher" : req.params.id
   }
},
```

Comment: Most likely you need to cast to `ObjectId`: `teacher:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work for me.@mickl

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get **ObjectID** from mongodb library and need to create new instance in following way.so that you will get the **ObjectID** of string. If your are using es6 in your code.

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';

var testQuery = [
          {
            $match: {
              teacher: new ObjectID(req.params.id)
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id:1,
              emailId:1,
              mobile:1
            }
          }
        ];
```